# Issue with asin() while calculating pi

Tags: c, windows, math, wolframalpha

I am trying to self teach myself C (C99 I think? gcc 8.1.0) coming from python/java. One of the practice problems I am working on is how to calculate pi to a given decimal.

I am currently using the following equation 2 * (Arcsin(sqrt(1 - 0.5^2)) + abs(Arcsin(0.5))).

```
float pi_find(float nth)
{
    float x, y, z;

    /* Equation = 2 * (Arcsin(sqrt(1 - x^2)) + abs(Arcsin(x))) [x|-1<=x=>1, xeR]*/
    x = sqrt(1-pow(nth, 2)); /* Carrot (^) notation does not work, use pow() */
    y = fabs(asin(nth)); /* abs is apparently int only, use fabs for floats */
    z = x+y;
    printf("x: %f\ny: %f\nsum: %f\n", x, y, (x+y));
    printf("%f\n", asin(z));
    return 2 * asin(z); /* <- Error Happens */
}
```

```
int main()
{
  float nth = 0.5f;

  double pi = pi_find(nth);

  printf("Pi: %f\n", pi);

  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
x: 0.866025
y:0.523599
sum: 1.389624
z:-1.#IND00
Pi:-1.#IND00
```

I know the issue lies in the addition of `x + y` which sums out to 1.389... and `asin()` can only handle values between -1 and +1 inclusive.

HOWEVER!

I am using Wolfram Alpha along side python to check the calc is correct at every step and it can calculate `asin(1.389...)`. [1]

I don't understand Imaginary mathematics, it is far beyond my capabilities as a mathematician but below is what Wolfram is doing. [2]

```
1.570796 -0.8563436 i
Interpreting as: 0.8563436 i
Assuming multiplication | Use a list instead
Assuming i is the imaginary unit | Use i as a variable instead
```

While writing this I found out about the `_Imaginary` Datatype added in C99, but I don't really understand if it's doing the same thing as what Wolfram does.

Also looked up how imaginary numbers worked, but I don't really understand how *'The square roots of a negative number cannot be distinguished until one of the two is defined as the imaginary unit'* works. [3]

Can someone nudge me in the direction to fix this please?
It is obviously a knowledge issue and not a mathematical or language limitation

p.s yes I know it's trash code, I am using a weird way of debugging before I rewrite it properly.

[1]:[Wolfram_Alpha Calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+*+%28Arcsin%28sqrt%281+-+0.5%5E2%29%29+%2B+abs%28Arcsin%280.5%29%29%29) 
[2]:[Wolfram_Alpha Assumption](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.570796+-%0A0.8563436+i&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D)
[3]:[Imaginary Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/i.html)

Comment: If you're using `asin` to calculate pi, then why not simply `pi = 2*asin(1)`?

Comment: @interjay Because I didn't know that worked and now I want to figure out this more complex method because it will teach me more about C. Thanks though. Always good to know there's a much simpler option out there

Comment: Looks like you aren't calculating the same thing as the equation. You aren't supposed to take the arcsin of the sum but of each operand.

Comment: @interjay That is exactly what happened... I even checked that like 3 times and still missed it. Thank you!

Comment: One thing you should do is change your `float` variables to `double`.  You're calling the double-precision versions of the math library functions, then (implicitly) casting the results down to `float`, discarding half of your precision in the process.  Then when you print them with `printf`, you're (implicitly) casting them back to `double`.  So the code is slower, larger, and less accurate than it would be if you kept the values as `double`.  I personally *never* use `float`.  It's very rare that it's ever needed these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're grouping the expression incorrectly.  The desired expression is:

2 * (Arcsin(sqrt(1 - 0.5^2)) + abs(Arcsin(0.5)))

With nth substituted for 0.5, this becomes:

2 * (Arcsin(sqrt(1 - nth^2)) + abs(Arcsin(nth))).

In particular, the argument to the first Arcsin is sqrt(1 - nth^2)), and the argument to the second Arcsin is nth.

You're also better off using `nth * nth` rather than `pow(nth, 2)`.  It's both faster and more accurate.

So what you want is:

```
x = asin(sqrt(1 - nth*nth));
y = fabs(asin(nth));
r = 2*(x + y);
```

Notice that the argument to `asin` can *never* have magnitude greater than 1 (as long as nth is less than 1).

Also, as I mentioned earlier in a comment, you should change all your `float` variables to `double`.  You're using the double-precision math library functions anyway, so there's no reason to discard half of the precision by storing the results in `float` variables.

Comment: Hmmm, `asin(sqrt(1 - nth*nth));` looks [simplifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions) as `acos(fabs(nth));`.

Comment: @chux Yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the `float` and `double` types model "real" numbers, which I'll assume you have a handle on.

In mathematics, ["complex" numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) are an extension of the real numbers.  Every real number counts as a complex number, but so do "imaginary numbers", which you can get by multiplying the real numbers by the "imaginary unit" (labeled `i` in mathematical notation, and conventionally described as "the square root of -1").

Mathematically speaking, the basic arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) are defined on complex numbers.  It turns out that you can extend functions like arcsine to operate on complex numbers as well.

Without getting any further into the details, the Wolfram Alpha is almost certainly giving you values from a complex version of arcsine.

However, the standard C function `asin()` is the un-extended version: it takes a `double` as an argument, and returns a `double` as a result.  Since `double` only models real numbers, `asin()` makes no sense for input values outside `[-1,1]`.

Comment: It may not "answer the primary question" but this is the sort of fantastic teaching I would have killed for back in HS/P2ndary. I did understand a bit about complex numbers since my HS maths teacher took a course on "abstract mathematics" that dealt with complex numbers, imaginary numbers and apparently a complicated way to describe a flower in math? Anyways. Thank you!